# KMP substring search Haskell

Tags: haskell

This needs to be marked a dup of "[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694306/knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-in-haskell)". if anyone can close this by marking it a dup would be great. Thanks.

After implementing KMP in C++ (imperative style), I'm now trying to implement it in Haskell. I came across this [post](https://www.twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/Knuth-Morris-Pratt-in-Haskell). I would like to understand how the "pre-processing" step of KMP is being done.

```
makeTable' []     failure = KMP True failure
makeTable' (x:xs) failure = KMP False test
   where  test  c = if c == x then success else failure c
          success = makeTable' xs (next (failure x))
```

I'm not able to understand how the table is being built. Especially with `table` being defined by calling it self `(const table)`. Where are the values of the table being carried?

```
makeTable :: Eq a => [a] -> KMP a
makeTable xs = table
   where table = makeTable' xs (const table)
```

Appreciate any help with understanding this. Please give me any pointers to read up on, that will be helpful in understanding this piece of Haskell code.

Thanks.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357956/explanation-of-tying-the-knot

Comment: Also see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Failure function used in KMP algorithm work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280924/how-does-the-failure-function-used-in-kmp-algorithm-work)